# Change netplan wifi encrypted password

Tags: ubuntu

I installed ubuntu using "Raspberry Pi Imager" in my raspberry pi.
Using Raspberry Pi Imager, I configured wifi to connect with.

[image]

[image]

Now after properly booting, when I check in my raspberry pi `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file, it shows some hexadecimal string in place of password :

[image]

Now I want to change password of wifi, so I need different hexadecimal string to set here. How to create that string and update wifi password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly I am surprised that this appeared to work (previously this was a Raspberry Pi OS only option). Maybe this might be because the latest imager includes options for NetworkManager.

This is only a guess but this looks like a standard 256 bit encoded psk.

These can be generated (on any Linux OS) with the following.

```
    wpa_passphrase <ssid> [passphrase]
```

PS Normally network details are stored under  `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` - you may be able to edit this (I haven't quite figured out this yaml stuff).

Comment: Hey, you are correct, it is wpa_passphrase. thanks bro.